# How to plot multiple plots in R for different variables

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, pie-chart

I have 5 genes and I want to plot their snp distribution in R.
So, basically 5 plots in R.

I tried to use loop for this but in my case it generate one plot only for a gene:

The code that I tried is:

```
set.seed(5)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
gene_exp <- read.table(file = "chr22_gene.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t" )
g <- round(runif(5,1,dim(gene_exp)[1])) ##creates 5 random var to select 5 random gene from chr22gene file
gene <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(gene_exp),"_"),`[`, 2)
for(i in g){
genename <- gene[g]
gene1 <- gene_exp %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  separate(rowname, into = c(NA, 'gene_name'), sep = '_') %>% 
  filter(gene_name == genename)

rsid_list <- NULL
snp <- strsplit(rownames(gene_exp), "_")
for(i in 1:dim(gene1)[1]){
  value <- snp[[i]][1]
  rsid_list <- rbind(rsid_list,value)
}

rownames(gene1) <- rsid_list
gene1 <- gene1[,-c(1)]

##pie plot: ##for same and different tissues:
pdf(paste0("rplot",sep="_",genename,".pdf"))

snp_onetissue <- dim(one_tissueonly)[1]
snp_difftissue <- dim(samesnp_difft)[1]
x <- c(snp_onetissue,snp_difftissue)
labels <- c("onesnp_onetissue","samesnp_differentissue")
#pie(x,labels)
pct <- round(x/sum(x)*100)
lbls <- paste(labels, pct) 
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") 

pie(x, labels=lbls,main = paste0("pie plot of snps for gene:",genename),col = rainbow(length(x)))
legend(0.8, 0.9, c("onesnp_onetissue","samesnp_differenttissue"), cex = 0.8,
       fill = rainbow(length(x)))
dev.off()
}
```

This code generate the plot but only for one gene.

Is there anyway to modify it to plot the pie chart for all the gene in separate pdf.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add sample data from the .txt file so we can reproduce the results?

Comment: In the middle-to-long run, getting familiar with ggplot will save you a ton of work for such purposes. For an instant solution, you can set up a multi-figure plot option (e. g. `par(mfrow = c(2, 3))` for a 2-by-3 panel plot), and proceed with your loop-approach.